# Problem about python import with error

Tags: python, import

I have write a small python module with one class and two functions. The skeleton of the module is as following:

```
#file name: test_module.py
class TestClass:
  @classmethod
  def method1(cls, param1):
    #to do something
    pass

  def __init__(self, param1):
    #to do something
    ...
def fun1(*params):
  #to do something
  ...

def fun2(*params):
  #to do something
  ...
```

Another py file is a small script which imports function and class from the module, as following:

```
    import sys
    from test_module import TestClass, fun1, fun2

    def main(sys_argv):
      li = range(5)
      inst1 = TestClass(li)
      fun1(inst1)
      fun2(inst1)
      return 

    if __name__ == "__main__":
      main(sys.argv)
```

But when I execute the script, it is broken with following message:

- from: can't read
  /var/mail/test_module
- ./script.py: line 4: syntax error
  near unexpected token `('
- ./script.py: line 4: `def
  main(sys_argv):'

I am not sure what the problem is. Is it a problem with import? But when I try to import the module in ipython, everything is just ok.

Comment: is the second python file properly indented?

Comment: @systempuntoout It is properly indented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a proper shebang line to your "small script". It's being interpreted as a shell script.